# symultanous wait for preocess complete in bash/ksh

Tags: bash, loops, ksh, simultaneous

I have a script for ran few commands simultaneously with 'nohup' command. Each of them create file as a confirmation of success.

How I can write loop or whatever for checking every then seconds for these files.

Each 'nohup' command create specific file, like as commadOneFile, commandTwoFile, ...

**Note:**
Each of 'nohup' command has a different time of execution.
I want to print dots on screen when waiting, or any other indicator for waiting and progress.

**Edit:**
For example

```
for command in COM1 COM2 COM3
do
    if [ "${command}" == "COM1" ]; then
            nohup $(ksh /run/my/commandOne.ksh)
    elif [ "${command}" == "COM2" ]; then
            nohup $(ksh /run/my/commandTwo.ksh)
    else [ "${command}" == "COM3" ]; then
            nohup $(ksh /run/my/commandThree.ksh)
done
```

Comment: What have you tried? It helps to put small code examples in your questions, people will be able to help you more precisely.

Comment: What if one of the sub-command scripts fails?  Is any file ever created?  Does the main script wait for all of the sub-commands to finish?  Does the main script wait indefinitely, or does it stop after a predetermined amount of time?

Comment: I have a control timer triger. If all script does not create their control files, main script will be aborted.

Answer (score 1):

As 'B Johnson' mentioned above, you must take account that one of the sub-commands can fail. Or else the while loop that you are looking for, will never end.
You can write the loop like this:

```
waitOne()
{
    while [ ! -f /path/to/fileOne ]; do
        sleep 10
    done
    echo -n "fileOne is created"
}
```

After running commandOne, run waitOne in the background.

Comment: Yea, but in this case (if i run this loop in background) main script does not have any control for child/nohup or wait for complete scripts. Main script can not show progress bar, or anything similar, that the user knows to execute nohup scripts in background.

I can make while loop for each nohup command, and execute one by one from main script for checking 'success file', but I want to run checking simultaneously for each script. Because, execute time for each script is different.

Comment: not sure from your original question, but are you trying to use a separate script to monitor if scripts are running? Would that help? Also do you know about running scripts in the background with `myScript &` ? You could have your 'for loop' start all scripts in background, then have a second 'for loop' that just checks for files. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I created function:

```
wait_d() {
    set -A COMPONENTS $@
    ii=0;
    while : 
    do
        echo -n "="
        sleep 10
        let ii++

        jj=0;
        for component in ${COMPONENTS[@]}
        do
            if [ -f ${STATUS_DIR}/${component}done ] ; then
                rm ${STATUS_DIR}/${component}done
                unset COMPONENTS[$jj]
            fi;
            let jj++
        done

        if [ ${#COMPONENTS[@]} == 0 ] ; then
            break;
        fi;
    done
}
```

BR
Kolesar